# Android - XML serialization - simpleframework - Path with Optional elements (required = false) - How to hide Null value elements?

Tags: android, xml-serialization, option-type, simple-framework

I want to use @PATH to keep order my elements, however, there are some optional elements (required = false), and I cannot hide these elements when their values are NULL.

```
@Order(elements={"Name", "Nickname"})
public class InfosType
{
    @Element
    @Path("Name")
    private String name;
    @Element(required=false)
    @Path("Nickname")
    private String nickname;
}
```

Even nickname = NULL, xml file always has Nickname field:

```
<Name>David</Name>    
<Nickname/>
```

But I want this:

```
<Name>David</Name>
```

My goal is to serialize xml file and keep order my optional elements.

Any suggestions for me (something for Android like simpleframework which can help me out, etc)? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution is Don't use Path.
I'm only using Order annotation.

```
@Order(elements={"Name", "Nickname"})
public class InfosType
{
    @Element(required = true,  name = "Name")
    private String name;
    @Element(required = false, name = "Nickname")
    private String nickname;
}
```

Since now simpleframework will not serialize NULL optional elements.